# Log4j2. How to solve constant problem with Log4J not finding appenders

Tags: spring-mvc, log4j, log4j2

```
INFO: Initialization processed in 2367 ms
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

We've all seen this message when starting Spring Web apps.  I have never been able to resolve this.  Now, I have to upgrade to Log4j2, I'd like end this annoyance.  I've searched and moved the log4j.properties file all over my app but never finds the appender.

Please can someone show me how the appender should be coded in log4j.properties, and where it's supposed to go in the web applicationl.

I am familiar with Log4j for many years, but can't seem to solve this one on the web application.

Answer (score 0):

Oh my.... It was a long hunt.  My problem was an old version of the jar still in my .classpath file.  And, it didn't have a log4j2.properties file.  Deleted the entry and voila!  I'm a lot smarter now on where to look for this problem.